# How can I make sure that a non-nullable type will always be inferred?

Tags: dart, generics

I'm currently making an API that I want the optional value of type `T` to **never** be nullable (having null-safety enabled, of course).

Let's exemplify with the following:

```dart
void main() {
  T nonNullableGeneric<T>(T value) {
    if(value == null) {
      throw 'This is null';
    }

    return value;
  }

  nonNullableGeneric(1); // Works fine
  
  nonNullableGeneric(null); // Works fine BUT I would like that the type inference would not allow a nullable value

  // Now this works as expected:
  // "the argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'."
  // 
  // ... but I have to specify the type `T`, which is not clear given my function signature, that clearly
  // requires a non-nullable value of type `T`
  nonNullableGeneric<int>(null);
  
  // How can I make the following call:
  // nonNullableGeneric(null)
  // to throw me something like "the argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to a parameter type 'T'."?
}
```

I've also created a [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/68b430d41d66779e67be5430302afdf5).

As you can see, I must always specify the type if I want to make sure that it can't be `Null`  when using a generic argument.

How can I make sure that it will never allow a nullable type?

Comment: Did you mean to do `if(value == null)` instead of `if(value != null)`? Seems a bit counterintuitive to throw "This is null" if what you have currently is correct. Nice answer btw!

Comment: @ChristopherMoore oh my, hahaha yes, I'm sorry and thanks for the edit (I always use optional <-> nullable because I came from a Swift background, you know, out of habit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found that the answer was really obvious, although I think it's reasonable to mention anyways: just make your type `T` constraints (extend) to a type of `Object`. This will make sure that that particular argument can never be optional.

Quoting the `Object` docs:

```dart
/// ...
/// Because `Object` is a root of the non-nullable Dart class hierarchy,
/// every other non-`Null` Dart class is a subclass of `Object`.
/// ...
```

So, in this example that I've mentioned, the solution would be:

```dart
void main() {
  T nonNullableGeneric<T extends Object>(T value) {
    return value;
  }

  nonNullableGeneric(1); // Works fine
   
  // Throws a:
  // Couldn't infer type parameter 'T'. Tried to infer 'Null' for 'T' which doesn't work: Type parameter 'T' declared to extend 'Object'.
  // The type 'Null' was inferred from: Parameter 'value' declared as 'T' but argument is 'Null'.
  // Consider passing explicit type argument(s) to the generic
  nonNullableGeneric(null);
}
```